# Como Python mantém a mesma referência de memória de uma lista após redimensioná-la?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, lista, característica-linguagem

Sabemos que os objetos do tipo `list`, por serem baseados em vetores dinâmicos, tem uma capacidade interna máxima. Também sabemos que quando está capacidade total é alcançada e quisermos inserir um novo valor na lista, Python aloca um novo *array* com uma capacidade maior que o anterior e transfere todos os valores do *array* anterior para o novo *array*. Mas como a linguagem aloca uma nova parcela da memória sem perder a referência da anterior?

```
lst = []
print(id(lst))

for i in range(999):
    lst.append(i)

print(id(lst))
```

Ao executar o código, podemos ver que os id's serão os iguais, mesmo depois das operações de redimensionamento. Como isso é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) retorna um identificador único da instância de um objeto. Ao redimensionar uma lista, apesar do objeto sofrer mudança em seu estado interno, a instância continua sendo a mesma, o que faz com que [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) sempre retorne o mesmo identificador.

Segue uma referência curiosa:

```
x = 1
y = x
x = y
z = 1

print(id(x))  # x referencia o inteiro 1
print(id(y))  # y referencia x
print(id(z))  # z referencia y
print(id(1))  # referencia para o inteiro 1

lst = []
copia = list(lst)
referencia = lst

# Altera somente estado interno da lista
for i in range(999):
    lst.append(i)

print(id(lst))         # id da lista original
print(id(copia))       # copia da lista possui uma instancia/id diferentes
print(id(referencia))  # referencia possui o mesma instancia/id da lista referenciada
```

Saída:

```
25037928
25037928
25037928
25037928
139864956135184
139864956180168
139864956135184
```

Answer (score 3):

Porque o objeto da lista não é a referência direta ao *array*, ele é uma estrutura com algumas informações, entre elas a referência para o *array* que compõe a lista. Esta é uma informação interna da linguagem, não interessa para o programador. O objeto da lista permanece o mesmo, mas o seu conteúdo muda, por isto o `id` não muda.

Uma [resposta no SO mostra detalhes da implementação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3958322/221800) (talvez hoje seja ligeiramente diferente, mas não muda muito).