# Função remove em uma lista altera elementos em outra Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
x = sequence
for i in range(len(x)):
    sequence = x
    cont = 0
    y = False
    sequence.remove(sequence[i])
    for j in range(len(sequence)):
        try:
            if sequence[j] < sequence[j+1]:
                cont += 1
                if cont == (len(sequence)-2):
                    y = True
        except:
            if sequence[-1] > sequence[-2]:
                    cont += 1
        if cont == len(sequence)-1:
            if y == True:
                pass
            else:
                y = False
return y
```

Estou com um problema nesse código, pois quando uso o remove na lista sequence, além dele remover o elemento na lista sequence, mas como também remove o mesmo elemento da lista x, gostaria de saber como consertar isso, ou caso não seja possível utilizando o remove, se é possível ter uma variavél para guardar a lista sequence sem que ela seja alterada.

Comment: O que esta função precisa fazer?

Comment: Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

Comment: Eu continuo com o mesmo problema, quando removo o item da lista sequence, ele continua excluindo da lista x também

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Python, as listas são mutáveis, o que significa que quando você passar uma lista por parâmetro para uma função, não será realizada a cópia do objeto, mas sim passado o próprio objeto. Qualquer modificação no objeto dentro da função, tal como o `remove`, será refletida no objeto fora da função.

Assim, por exemplo, se eu passar uma lista de dois valores para uma função e nesta remover o último elemento, fora da função também terei uma lista de um elemento.

```
def remover_ultimo_elemento(lista):
    lista.pop()

lista = [1, 2]
remover_ultimo_elemento(lista)

print(lista)  # [1]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AzureQuizzicalPatch) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/GW539c)</sup>

Sobre isso você pode ler também aqui:

- [Como passar argumentos por referência em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255451/5878)
- [Referência e Parâmetro em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197681/5878)
- [Como Python mantém a mesma referência de memória de uma lista após redimensioná-la?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245019/5878)
- [Como passar argumentos por valor no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187869/5878)

Mas perceba que em nenhum momento o enunciado do problema pede para remover o elemento da lista; o que se pede é para determinar se, a partir da lista de entrada, é possível criar uma lista estritamente crescente removendo apenas um elemento. Uma lista é considerada estritamente crescente se para qualquer valor `a[n]` da lista seja menor que `a[n+1]` - perceba que é menor, não menor ou igual.

Ou seja, para fazer a verificação, basta você percorrer a lista em pares de valores e verificar se o primeiro valor é menor que o segundo. Se o primeiro for maior ou igual ao segundo nenhuma ou uma vez na lista inteira, então o retorno será verdadeiro; caso contrário, falso.

```
def is_strictly_increasing(numbers):
    counter = 0
    for a, b in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
        if a >= b:
            counter += 1
    return counter <= 1

print(is_strictly_increasing([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))  # True
print(is_strictly_increasing([1, 2, 3, 3, 5]))  # True
print(is_strictly_increasing([1, 2, 2, 1, 5]))  # False
```

Ou em sua forma resumida:

```
def is_strictly_increasing(numbers):
    counter = sum(1 if a >= b else 0 for a, b in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]))
    return counter <= 1
```

Comment: Excelente solução ao problema! Como não podia deixar de ser, python resolve o problema com uma linha :D

Comment: Muito obrigado, me esclareceu bastante. =D

Answer (score 1):

Em Python quando você faz `list1 = list2` então as duas listas apontarão para o mesmo objeto e mudar o valor de uma implica em mudar o valor de outra. Você pode resolver o seu problema fazendo uma cópia da lista utilizando `list.copy()`.

Gostaria de adicionar que como você fez `x = sequence` antes do loop e `sequence = x` após o loop então mesmo que você utilize a cópia que sugeri acima, você vai voltar a apontar para o mesmo objeto. Ex.: `x = sequence.copy()`